# Variable assignment in C++ (with libpng) not working?

Tags: c++, png, variable-assignment, libpng

I'm writing a texture loader, attempting to use libpng with it. I am currently stumped on one tiny part, which makes no sense. I'm trying to get the image width and height, and am finding that the returned values are not saving.

```
unsigned int width;
unsigned int height;

...

width = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr);
height = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr);

printf("Width: %d\nHeight: %d\n\n", width, height);
printf("Width: %d\nHeight: %d\n\n", png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr), png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr));
```

This returns the following:

```
Width: 0
Height: 0

Width: 1024
Height: 2048
```

So what's the deal? This **should** work, but it is very clearly not.

Pastbin of all relevent code: http://pastebin.com/9RP1iqqU

Comment: You should be using `%ud` for unsigned integers IIRC. Not sure if that solves it.

Comment: That doesn't help, and just gives me "Width: 0d" rather than "Width: 0"

Also, I have tried both signed and unsigned ints.

Comment: Can you provide a short (20 lines or so) complete sample program that demonstrates the error? See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Yes, we would like to see the adventures of `width` and `height` down the way to `printf`, please.

Comment: @Katherine1, Oh, guess I meant `%u`. Anyway, if that didn't work, we need an SSCCE.

Comment: Here's a pastebin of the relevant code: http://pastebin.com/9RP1iqqU

Comment: Updated my answer after reading your pastebin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong type.  `width` and `height` should be `png_uint_32` not `unsigned int`

UPDATE:

After seeing your pastebin, it looks like you're passing in `width` and `height` to the function as `unsigned char` which are effectively hiding the class members `width` and `height` and is probably not what you want, specifically since `unsigned char` can only hold values up to 255 and the width and height are 1024 and 2048.

Just rename the function parameters.

Comment: Ahh @Tony just beat me to it! :)

Comment: You need to put more (mostly useless) code in your answer to beat him back, a typical novice mistake.. :)

Comment: tileWidth and TileHeight are different values. Those are the size of the textures contained in the image, not the image's size itself. I am not saving those values to width or height.

Comment: Although... I see a naming problem that could be doing that.

Comment: Please look at your code again.  You might call them `tileWidth` and `tileHeight` in your definition but the implementation calls them `width` and `height`

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted [here](http://pastebin.com/9RP1iqqU), I may assume that he names of your member data in `TextureAtlas` class conflict with the names of the parameters in `loadAtlas` member function.

```
class TextureAtlas {
    protected:
        unsigned int width;
        unsigned int height;

    public:

        TextureAtlas();
        virtual ~TextureAtlas();

        void loadAtlas(std::string loc, unsigned char tileWidth, unsigned char tileHeight);
};

void TextureAtlas::loadAtlas(std::string loc, unsigned char width, unsigned char height) {
    ...
    width = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    height = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    color_type = png_get_color_type(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    bit_depth = png_get_bit_depth(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    printf("Width: %d\nHeight: %d\n\n", width, height);
    printf("Width: %d\nHeight: %d\n\n", png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr), png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr));
    ...
```

Either rename

```
unsigned int width;
unsigned int height;
```

or the last two parameters in

```
void TextureAtlas::loadAtlas(std::string loc, unsigned char width, unsigned char height)
```

Comment: Correct, this is exactly what I said in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may lie in the fact you're using `unsigned int` to store the return type in, when in actual fact the return type is `png_uint_32`.

Have you tried doing this:

```
 png_uint_32 width = 0;
 png_uint_32 height = 0;

 width = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr);
 height = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr);
```

I haven't tried it, but I suspect very much that's the problem.

Comment: `typedef unsigned long int png_uint_32;` The only difference is the `long`, which for me, at least, is the same without. I was kind of wondering why it wouldn't be a normal int of some sort to produce that behaviour.

Comment: @chris I'm guessing this will all depend on what platform and the size of the CPU used.  That's why it's a good idea to just used the `png_uint_32` and not `unsigned int`.

Comment: @TonyTheLion, Definitely; I was just pointing out how it would work the same way for me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying the set the class members called `width` and `height`; however, you've hidden these with function parameters with the same names. These have type `unsigned char`, which (almost certainly) can't hold values larger than 256, which is why you see zero when you print them.

You can fix it by:

- renaming either the arguments or the member variables so they don't clash; or
- accessing the members as `this->width` and `this->height`